# python pandas divide dataframe in method chain

Tags: pandas

I want to divide a dataframe by a number:

```
df = df/10
```

Is there a way to do this in a method chain?

```
# idea:
df = df.filter(['a','b']).query("a>100").assign(**divide by 10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `DataFrame.div` here:

```
df = df[['a','b']].query("a>100").div(10)
```

```
      a    b
0  40.0  0.7
1  50.0  0.8
5  70.0  0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) with lambda function for use some function for all data of DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     
         'a':[400,500,40,50,5,700],
         'b':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'c':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'd':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})

df = df.filter(['a','b']).query("a>100").pipe(lambda x: x / 10)
print (df)
      a    b
0  40.0  0.7
1  50.0  0.8
5  70.0  0.3
```

Here if use apply all columns are divided separately:

```
df = df.filter(['a','b']).query("a>100").apply(lambda x: x / 10)
```

You can see difference with `print`:

```
df1 = df.filter(['a','b']).query("a>100").pipe(lambda x: print (x))
     a  b
0  400  7
1  500  8
5  700  3

df2 = df.filter(['a','b']).query("a>100").apply(lambda x: print (x))
0    400
1    500
5    700
Name: a, dtype: int64
0    7
1    8
5    3
Name: b, dtype: int64
```